# What does "user" means for Cloud Storage Transfer Service quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

[The Cloud Storage Transfer document](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/quotas) says there are quotas "per user" for transferJobs create, patch, and transferOperations.

Does anyone knows what exactly means this "user"?
IAM who calls requests?

Answer (score 1):

Quota per user means the quota that each user has to use this service, for example: the user "JonSnow@got.com" has a "Maximum requests per 100 seconds per user: 514"

So, if the project has a "Maximum requests per 100 seconds per project: 2500", means that if "JonSnow@got.com" has reached the limit of 514 requests, "DaenerysTargaryen@got.com", "TyrionLannister@got.com" and "AryaStark@got.com" can use 514 requests per 100 seconds too. However, "Joffrey@got.com" only can use 444 requests per 100 seconds due to all the GOT team has reached the "Maximum requests per 100 seconds per project: 2500".